# Windows form open new form to display data

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, .net-4.5

See below image - In my database I have 3 columns that I am interested in displaying the results through my windows form. In this example I have selected the "Spaghetti Meatballs" recipe from the database and clicked the Retrieve button, what happens then is the two text box's that I have placed to the right will populate, one with the ingredients and one with the steps to cook. Please ignore the method in which I have stored the data for the time being as that is not my current issue.

**Question**

The basic functionality that I want is working in the sense that I can display basic information associated to the user selection from the drop down menu albeit not very nicely. What I want however is when the user clicks the retrieve button a new window will pop-up and display the title, picture, ingredients and steps for that recipe. Now, I've already added a new form to the project named Pop_up.cs however I am unsure how I change the 'Retrieve' method to firstly bring up that form, and secondly populate the textbox's/picture boxes that I will place on the form with the data specified from the user in form1 and retrieved from my database.

**Retrieve Method**

```
   //R E T R I E V E     B U T T O N 
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dataTable = dset.Tables[0];

            if (pictureBox2.Image != null)
            {
                pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
            }

            FileStream FS1 = new FileStream("image.jpg", FileMode.Create);

            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
            {

                if (dataRow[0].ToString() == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {

                    byte[] blob = (byte[])dataRow[1];
                    FS1.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                    FS1.Close();
                    FS1 = null;
                    label5.Text = dataRow[3].ToString();
                    label6.Text = dataRow[2].ToString();
                    pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("image.jpg");
                    pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    pictureBox2.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: you want to display the recipe info on new form right? please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: First, I would create a Recipe class to make the code more readable.  Then, I would instantiate a Recipe object when the user selects a recipe, and I would send that Recipe to the new Form2 as a parameter.

Comment: @Sudhakar Yes, everything in the bottom right hand corner of the image i.e the pic, instructions and ingredients needs to open in a new window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the Pop_up class's constructor to take a parameter . And write a FillData() method to load the recipe data from the database

```
public partial class Pop_up : Form
    {
        public Pop_up(string recipe)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillData(recipe);

        }
    }
```

In the Retrive button's code show the Pop_up . Pass the Receipe name as the argument

```
 //R E T R I E V E     B U T T O N 
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string recipeName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
      Pop_up p = new Pop_up(recipeName);
      p.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Would I place the pop_up class's constructor addition in my form1.cs?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question.Are you asking about the FillData method?

Comment: When you refer to the Pop_up class, are you referring to my additional form that I want to open? If so why am I instantiating my form as 'p'? Excuse my ignorance

Comment: you can use an arbitrary name whatever you want in place of 'p'

Comment: @SelectDistinct Yes  Pop_up is your additional form. p is just a variable name , you can use what you like instead .

Comment: @gawicks sorry for the late flag, only got time to implement this last night and it worked a treat, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Pop_up.cs has the following controls

```
PictureBox pictureBox;
Label labelIngredients;
Label labelCookSteps;
```

Then Pop_up.cs may look like:

```
public partial class Pop_up : Form
{
    public Pop_up()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
    }

    public Pop_up(string recipeName, DataSet dset)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindDataContext(recipeName, dset);

    }

    private void BindDataContext(string recipeName, DataSet dset)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = dset.Tables[0];

        if (pictureBox.Image != null)
        {
            pictureBox.Image.Dispose();
        }

        FileStream FS1 = new FileStream("image.jpg", FileMode.Create);

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {

            if (dataRow[0].ToString() == recipeName)
            {
                byte[] blob = (byte[])dataRow[1];
                FS1.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                FS1.Close();
                FS1 = null;
                labelIngredients.Text = dataRow[3].ToString();
                labelCookSteps.Text = dataRow[2].ToString();
                pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("image.jpg");
                pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pictureBox.Refresh();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Then Retrieve button inside Form1.cs may look like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //R E T R I E V E     B U T T O N 
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string recipeName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
      Pop_up p = new Pop_up(recipeName, dset);
      p.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll and it breaks on FileSteam FS1 = new FileSteam in Pop_up.cs

Comment: Sorry ignore that, its because my original form was still trying to use FileSteam at the same time, commenting out one or the other will solve this issue